# Advanced CSS Challenge

Tags: css, sass

I have a few cards in a row. The effect that I'm trying to achieve: 
On hover, the card should grow and show some hidden parts. I was able to achieve that, but with 2 drawbacks.

1. The central part of the card (the title) is not staying aligned with the other card titles when one of the cards is in the active state (on hover).
2. When hovering, the card folds downwards. I want the effect/UX to be like the card is 'pushing' the content above it and below it, which means, if you put your cursor on the title, it'll stay on the title, and the rest of the page will move upwards and downwards

The page is [under development here](http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/industry/medical-devices/)

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkixx.jpg

Note: [Bootstrap CSS](https://getbootstrap.com) is also included

SCSS:

```
.industry-cycle {
.cycle-row {
    z-index:5;
    @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
        align-items: center;
    }
}
.cycle-step {
    z-index: 5;
    .trans {
        transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    width: 95%;
    border-radius: $border-radius;
    background-color: white;
    .cycle-title {
        min-height: 130px;
        padding-top: 14px;
        padding-bottom: 14px;
    }
    .show-on-hover {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        max-height: 0px;
    }
    li {
        font-size: 18px;
        @include media-breakpoint-up(xxl) {
            font-size: 22px;
        }
    }
    &:hover {
        .show-on-hover {
            max-height: 400px;
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .cycle-title {
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
                min-height: 130px;
            }
        }
    }
    @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
        .show-on-hover {
            max-height: 400px;
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .cycle-title {
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            min-height: 80px;
        } 
    }
    
}
.next-step {
    right: -8px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    font-size: 33px;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
}
.cycle-dots {
    z-index: 0;
    top: -80px;
}

hr {
    width: 95%;
    border-top: 3px solid $primary-blue;
}

.cycle-item-list {
    list-style-type: circle;
}
}
```

CSS

```
section.industry-map {
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #fff 0%, #eeeff1 100%) 0% 0%
    no-repeat padding-box;
}
section.industry-map .description {
  color: #8b8b8b;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section.industry-map .map-content {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section.industry-map .map-content {
    width: 520px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section.industry-map .map-image {
    width: calc(100% - 400px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  section.industry-map .map-image {
    width: calc(100% - 520px);
  }
}
section.industry-map .map-image svg {
  max-width: 100%;
}
section.industry-map .map-image svg path {
  transition: all 0.32s ease;
}
section.industry-map .map-image svg .map-el-active {
  fill: #0e76bc;
}
section.industry-map .map-image svg .map-el-active path {
  fill: #0e76bc;
}
section.industry-map ul.map-regions li.one-region {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0e76bc;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section.industry-map ul.map-regions li.one-region {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #0e76bc;
    padding-top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1379.98px) {
  section.industry-map ul.map-regions li.one-region svg {
    width: 60px;
  }
}
section.industry-map ul.map-regions li.one-region h3 {
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal bold 25px/29px Rubik;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #343434;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
section.industry-map ul.map-regions li.one-region h4 {
  font: normal normal normal 25px/29px Rubik;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #343434;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
section.industry-map ul.map-regions li.one-region.map-el-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.sectionTitle {
  scroll-margin-top: 150px;
}
@media (max-width: 1023.98px) {
  .industry-hero h1 {
    font-size: 32px !important;
  }
}
.industry-hero .logo-industry {
  width: 141px;
  height: 144px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .industry-hero .logo-industry {
    top: 56px;
  }
}
.industry-hero .filter {
  top: 0px;
}
.industry-hero .industry-head-menu {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #0e76bc;
  height: 60px;
  top: 95px;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}
.industry-hero .industry-head-menu ul {
  margin-top: 13px;
  float: right;
}
.industry-hero .industry-head-menu ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .industry-hero .industry-head-menu ul li {
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
}
.industry-hero .industry-head-menu span {
  margin-top: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .industry-hero .industry-head-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
.industry-cycle .cycle-row {
  z-index: 5;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .industry-cycle .cycle-row {
    align-items: center;
  }
}
.industry-cycle .cycle-step {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 95%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}
.industry-cycle .cycle-step .trans {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.industry-cycle .cycle-step .cycle-title {
  min-height: 130px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}
.industry-cycle .cycle-step .show-on-hover {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
}
.industry-cycle .cycle-step li {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 1380px) {
  .industry-cycle .cycle-step li {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}
.industry-cycle .cycle-step:hover .show-on-hover {
  max-height: 400px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.industry-cycle .cycle-step:hover .cycle-title {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .industry-cycle .cycle-step:hover .cycle-title {
    min-height: 130px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1023.98px) {
  .industry-cycle .cycle-step .show-on-hover {
    max-height: 400px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .industry-cycle .cycle-step .cycle-title {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    min-height: 80px;
  }
}
.industry-cycle .next-step {
  right: -8px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  font-size: 33px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
}
.industry-cycle .cycle-dots {
  z-index: 0;
  top: -80px;
}
.industry-cycle hr {
  width: 95%;
  border-top: 3px solid #0e76bc;
}
.industry-cycle .cycle-item-list {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
.industry-services {
  z-index: 1;
}
.industry-services .service-button {
  padding-top: 17px !important;
  padding-bottom: 17px !important;
  border-radius: 32px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
@media (min-width: 1380px) {
  .industry-services .service-button {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}
.industry-services .service-title {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.industry-services .serivce-text p {
  line-height: 34px;
}
.industry-services .opac-butt {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.industry-services .reg-butt {
  opacity: 1;
}
.industry-experts a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #343434;
}
.industry-experts a svg {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.industry-experts h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.industry-our-customers h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
}
.industry-our-customers h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.industry-our-customers h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.industry-our-customers p {
  line-height: 25px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .industry-our-customers p {
    line-height: 34px;
  }
}
.industry-our-customers hr {
  width: 105px;
}
.industry-our-customers img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 96px;
  width: 96px;
}
.trans-ser-button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  outline: none;
}
.carousel-wrapper button {
  top: 45px;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.carousel-wrapper button.prev {
  left: -35px;
}
.carousel-wrapper button.next {
  right: -35px;
}
.carousel-wrapper button svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
.industry-courses hr {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0px;
  border-color: #343434;
}
.industry-courses h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.industry-courses .service {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.industry-courses button {
  font-size: 22px !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
  padding-left: 25px !important;
  padding-right: 25px !important;
  outline: none;
}
.industry-courses a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML (only the section)

```
<section class="industry-cycle pt-4 position-relative">
<div class="position-absolute to-right d-none d-xl-block cycle-dots">
        <img src="http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/pinl-graphics-services-1.png" srcset="http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/pinl-graphics-services-1-300x257.png 300w, http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/pinl-graphics-services-1-768x658.png 768w, http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/pinl-graphics-services-1.png 945w" alt="" width="945" height="810">
</div>
  <div class="container pb-5 mb-5">
    <h3 class="primary-blue text-uppercase">Medical Devices LIFE CYCLE</h3>
    <p class="primary-blue">We are Your partners from idea to Market compliance!</p>
    <div class="row pt-3 cycle-row align-align-items-center">
                <div class="pt-4 pt-xl-0 col-12 col-xl position-relative">
            <div class="trans cycle-step d-flex flex-column align-items-center shadow position-relative">
                              <div>
                                <img class="trans p-2 show-on-hover site-border-radius" src="http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/annie-spratt-MChSQHxGZrQ-2unsplash.png" srcset="http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/annie-spratt-MChSQHxGZrQ-2unsplash-300x141.png 300w, http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/annie-spratt-MChSQHxGZrQ-2unsplash.png 495w" alt="" width="auto" height="auto" style="max-width: 100%">  
                </div>
                              <div class="cycle-title d-flex align-items-center">
                  <h3 class="trans text-center primary-blue font-weight-normal">Planning of Product realization</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="trans show-on-hover w-100 pb-3 cycle-list">
                  <hr>
                  <ul class="cycle-item-list pr-2 pl-5">
                                        <li>
                      Product classification                     </li>
                                        <li>
                      Regulatory strategy                    </li>
                                        <li>
                      Clinical strategy                    </li>
                                      </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                            <span class="d-none d-xl-block next-step position-absolute primary-blue"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-chevron-right" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"></path>
</svg></span>
                    </div>
                <div class="pt-4 pt-xl-0 col-12 col-xl position-relative">
            <div class="trans cycle-step d-flex flex-column align-items-center shadow position-relative">
                              <div>
                                <img class="trans p-2 show-on-hover site-border-radius" src="http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/3d-printer-printing-prototype-from-eco-friendly-biodegradable-filament-polymer_t20_e9zRyB-aspect-ratio-450-187.jpg" srcset="http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/3d-printer-printing-prototype-from-eco-friendly-biodegradable-filament-polymer_t20_e9zRyB-aspect-ratio-450-187-300x125.jpg 300w, http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/3d-printer-printing-prototype-from-eco-friendly-biodegradable-filament-polymer_t20_e9zRyB-aspect-ratio-450-187-1024x426.jpg 1024w, http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/3d-printer-printing-prototype-from-eco-friendly-biodegradable-filament-polymer_t20_e9zRyB-aspect-ratio-450-187-768x319.jpg 768w, http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/3d-printer-printing-prototype-from-eco-friendly-biodegradable-filament-polymer_t20_e9zRyB-aspect-ratio-450-187.jpg 1039w" alt="" width="auto" height="auto" style="max-width: 100%">  
                </div>
                              <div class="cycle-title d-flex align-items-center">
                  <h3 class="trans text-center primary-blue font-weight-normal">Design &amp; Development</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="trans show-on-hover w-100 pb-3 cycle-list">
                  <hr>
                  <ul class="cycle-item-list pr-2 pl-5">
                                        <li>
                      Quality plan and  design input                    </li>
                                        <li>
                      Design output                    </li>
                                        <li>
                      Validation and verification                    </li>
                                        <li>
                      Preclinical and clinical trials                    </li>
                                      </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                            <span class="d-none d-xl-block next-step position-absolute primary-blue"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-chevron-right" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"></path>
</svg></span>
                    </div>
                <div class="pt-4 pt-xl-0 col-12 col-xl position-relative">
            <div class="trans cycle-step d-flex flex-column align-items-center shadow position-relative">
                              <div>
                                <img class="trans p-2 show-on-hover site-border-radius" src="http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/sales-manager-filing-keys-to-customer-after-signing-rental-lease-contract-of-sale-purchase-agreement_t20_98rngB-aspect-ratio-450-187.jpg" srcset="http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/sales-manager-filing-keys-to-customer-after-signing-rental-lease-contract-of-sale-purchase-agreement_t20_98rngB-aspect-ratio-450-187-300x125.jpg 300w, http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/sales-manager-filing-keys-to-customer-after-signing-rental-lease-contract-of-sale-purchase-agreement_t20_98rngB-aspect-ratio-450-187-1024x426.jpg 1024w, http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/sales-manager-filing-keys-to-customer-after-signing-rental-lease-contract-of-sale-purchase-agreement_t20_98rngB-aspect-ratio-450-187-768x319.jpg 768w, http://gsap.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/sales-manager-filing-keys-to-customer-after-signing-rental-lease-contract-of-sale-purchase-agreement_t20_98rngB-aspect-ratio-450-187.jpg 1049w" alt="" width="auto" height="auto" style="max-width: 100%">  
                </div>
                              <div class="cycle-title d-flex align-items-center">
                  <h3 class="trans text-center primary-blue font-weight-normal">Marketing</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="trans show-on-hover w-100 pb-3 cycle-list">
                  <hr>
                  <ul class="cycle-item-list pr-2 pl-5">
                                        <li>
                      Regulatory submission clearance &amp; approval                    </li>
                                        <li>
                      Transfer to production                    </li>
                                        <li>
                      Post market activities                    </li>
                                      </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML here. And your rendered CSS. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The titles are aligned on Mac Firefox. I can't see how the expanded content should push the content above it upwards. You can't push anything higher than the top of the page. A solution could be to let the expansions overlap the elements above and below the title.